# How to get a dict key and value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Imagine I have a `dict` like this:

```
d = {'key': 'value'}
```

The `dict` contains only one key value.
I am trying to get `key` from this `dict`, I tried `d.keys()[0]` but it returns `IndexError`, I tried this:

```
list(d.keys())[0]
```

It works just fine but I think it is not a good way of doing this because it creates a new list and then get it first index.

Is there a better way to do this? I want to get the `value` too.

Comment: @PatrickArtner No, it returns an array of tuples that dose not support `Indexing` either.

Comment: and `d.items()[0]` returns `IndexError` same as `.keys()`

Comment: YOure right. `items()` is just a [view](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)

Comment: Maybe: `next(i for i in d.keys())`

Comment: @AntonvBR come on, loop for a single item dict ?

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar It starts a loop but exits at first occurence.

Comment: @AntonvBR but I think `list(d.keys())[0]` can be better.

Comment: For Python 3:

    next(iter(d.values()))

Python 2:

    d.itervalues().next()

For an empty dictionary you need do extra errorhandling (StopIteration error).

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar Well if the size if 1 maybe. But if you have a large one next will be much quicker.

Comment: next(iter(d.items())) would be the best solution for large dictionaries

Comment: I'm not sure what is the question. You know how to access the key and the value, you state that you only have a single item in your dict so what is the problem? Creating a list a one element (or the generator from @AntonvBR) is not expensive. If you do that many times or don't consider it esthetically acceptable, maybe you should consider not using a mapping for a single item but just a tuple `(key, value)` for instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know (or expect) there is exactly one key / value pair then you could use unpacking to get the key and the value. eg.

```
[item] = d.items()
assert item == ('key', 'value')
```

You can take this one step further and unpack the key / value pair too.

```
[[k, v]] = d.items()
assert k == 'key'
assert v == 'value'
```

Of course this throws an error if the dictionary has multiple key / value pairs. But then this is useful. Dictionaries are unordered pre python 3.7 (`dict` is ordered in CPython 3.6, but it's an implementation detail), so doing `list(d.items())[0]` can give inconsistent results. Even in 3.7+ the ordering is over insertion, not any natural ordering of the keys, so you could still get surprising results.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the silly way:

```
def silly(d:dict):
    for k,v in d.items():
        return (k,v) # will only ever return the "first" one 
                     # with 3.7 thats the first inserted one
```

Using

```
list(d.items())[0]
```

at least gives you *key* and *value* at once (and throw on empty dicts).

With dictionarys being "insert-ordered" from 3.7 onwards there might evolve some methods to *"get the first"* or *"get the last"* of it, but so far `dict` were unordered and indexing into them (or getting first/last) made no sense.

Answer (score -2):

There is some information for you below, but I believe that you don't fully understand dictionaries. They are unsorted, meaning that the list created will be in random order, so indexing will return unpredictable answers.

Since Python 3, d.keys() no longer returns a list, and instead returns a dictionary object which doesn't support indexing and subsequently would return IndexError. Unfortunately, you will simply have to use list().

If the option is available (i.e. You are going to loop through the list), you could go:

```
for item in d.keys():
    # Do something
```

which means that you don't have to convert it to a list.

Comment: 3.7: they are "sorted" ... https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html